# (Anylogic) How to reference Main from another agent

Tags: reference, connection, program-entry-point, anylogic, agent

**How Do I Reference Main From Within An Agent?**
I have a resourcepool of 1 of an agent moving items in Main. There the process is modelled with The Process Modelling Library. The Agent does neither Enter not Exit the Process Model, but perists indefinitely.
I now wish to add a statechart to my agent, in which I want to test if the agent arrived at a certain Queue Block in Main. However, I cannot reference Main from my agent's statechart. Neither '*get_Main()*' nor '*main*' work, as I also don't have the arrow with main on it (I have seen this on reference models).
I'm using Anylogic 8.1 
[The main arrow I found in reference models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6xg5.png)

Edit: solution i found: Use a variable and set it to Main, you can reference items in Main over this variable.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. embedd an agent population on Main and make your ResourcePool add agents to that on creation. This will give you the `main` link
2. Use `getEngine().getRoot()` at any point in your model. As long as your top-level agent is `Main` (normal case), this will work. You may have to type-cast it as `((Main)getEngine().getRoot())`